Is it possilbe to programmaticaly convert an interface into a discriminated union based on the interface's keys?
Let's say I have an interface such as:
interface DataShapes {
  shape1: { a: number };
  shape2: { b: string };
}

Is it possible to define a type ToUnion such that ToUnion<DataShapes> produces a discriminated union like:
 | { key: 'shape1', value: { a: number } }
 | { key: 'shape2', value: { b: string } }


Yes it is possible, here's a way to do it:
Playground
interface DataShapes {
  shape1: { a: number };
  shape2: { b: string };
}

type ToUnion<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        key: K,
        value: T[K]
    }
}[keyof T]

type A = ToUnion<DataShapes>


type ToUnion<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];

interface DataShapes {
  shape1: { a: number };
  shape2: { b: string };
}

type Result = ToUnion<DataShapes>;
// {
//     key: "shape1";
//     value: {
//         a: number;
//     };
// } | {
//     key: "shape2";
//     value: {
//         b: string;
//     };
// }

TS Playground
